# Grease Pencil: How to get rid of "line mode"?

Tags: grease-pencil

My Problem: I'm working normally with Grease Pencil, switching between Draw & Editmode, and edit keyframes. I do not touch any options or change any pencils.
All of a sudden going back to Drawmode, blender starts only drawing perfect lines. Already drawn stuff starts disappearing. My inputs get ignored, I can literally only draw perfect lines. When I try to go back a step, in every second try Blender crashes. I can't figure out a way to get rid of this "mode" other than starting a new project.

So let me be clear: I know there is a Line tool for grease pencil, and I explicitly **don't** want to draw lines, and i dont have the line tool selected. I just want to use the normal draw mode, and didn't (knowingly) change any options.

I'm using the newest version of Blender (2.83.3) & an XPEN Artist 12 Tablet + normal mouse controls.

Thanks in Advance.